# .htaccess is only recognized when it is not specific to a particular file. Why?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I am currently trying to protect a file with a login on my Apache server using the .htaccess file. However, it only works when I don't use the following:

```
<Files level1.html>
# htaccess
</Files>
```

Yes, the file exists, and the path is correct. The permissions also seem to be correct (-rwxr-xr-x). Now, I don't understand why this is the case. Does anyone know what could be done?

Here is the .htaccess file without the inclusion of level1.html:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Level 1"
AuthUserFile /home/user/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I tried changing permissions to anything really, I checked all the apache configs and didn't see anything special in particular, I checked all the file paths. I expected a login alert to show up upon entering site.url/level1.html which did not happen.

Comment: Do you see a corresponding entry in your http server's error log file?

Comment: "Yes, the file exists, **and the path is correct**." - Although there is no "path" specified? But the `<Files>` directive does not take a path - if you do specify a path then it will fail to match and do nothing. "it only works when I don't use the following" - You mean use a `<Files>` wrapper? Do you have any other directives in your config file? What version of Apache are you using?